# Точка на границе полигона

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, функции

Есть ли в PostgreSQL функция, определяющая, лежит ли точка на границе полигона или является его вершиной?

Comment: Серьезно? PostgreSQL у нас теперь графический движок? и как вы не зная "вершин" полигона собрались определять не является ли точка его вершиной?

Comment: Наверно сарказм Ваш надо немного поумерить объяснив задачу. В одной таблице я имею полигоны POLYGON(), в другой таблице точки POINT(). Проверку на попадание точки в полигон осуществляю функцией '@>'. Но я допускаю, что некоторые точки могут лежать на границах полигонов или на их вершинах.

Comment: Наверное ответа вы врятли получите, по той простой причине что понятней не стало от слова совсем =) У вас есть база данных и вы хотите на ее стороне делать какие то математические операции =) это всё что понятно на данный момент =) Ни **описания структуры таблиц**, ни описания **что вы уже сделали сами** - нету, ни **вменяемого описания желаемого результата** тем более - **нету**. И после этого вы еще говорите о моем сарказме?) И да, мой вам ответ заранее - **БАЗА ДАННЫХ ДОЛЖНА ЗАНИМАТЬСЯ ХРАНЕНИЕМ И ВЫДАЧЕЙ ДАННЫХ**, а никак не их обработкой и модификацией =)